# Solr 9.2 with JDK 17 : Java script engine not found

Tags: solr, openjdk-12

I am ugrading my Solr from 8.4 to 9.2 and Java from 11 to 17. Since JDK 12 nashorn java scripts are  removed.

Question: How are you using Solr ScriptUpdateProcessorFactory with JDK 12 or up?

Error :

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to initialize scripts: No ScriptEngine found by file extension: update-script.js -- supported extensions:

What I have tried so far:

1. Enabled te scripting module
2. Renamed the class from StatelessScriptingUpdateProcessor to  ScriptUpdateProcessorFactory